# In this example, is dynamic_cast the solution?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

#### The Problem

I have different classes that are some sort of `Manager`, i.e, they manage classes called `Entities`. There may be a lot of different `Manager` classes, but they all have one method in common, `addEntity`.

Example:

```
class AManager
{
    addEntity(Entity e, AContract contract);
}

class BManager
{
    addEntity(Entity, BContract contract);
}

 ...
```

Now I want at any given time have the possibility to add a `Entity` to any of this classes, given that I also give the classe's `Contract` (class with only data) as well. Note that up until now there is no kind of inheritance whatsoever.

This classes should not be directly accessible to the user as well, so they are accessible from another class called `ComponentManager`, which stores references to this `XManagers`. So in the class `ComponentManager` I want to add this method.

```
enum class ManagerType
{
    A, B, // ...
}

class ComponentManager
{
public:
    addEntityToManager(Entity e, XContract, ManagerType type);
private:
    // References to all manager classes
}
```

The reason I want to do that, is that it is not practical to create one different method for each `Manager` (`addEntityToXManager`), because there may be a lot of them. So it would be nice to just pass an `Enum`, and the correct method is called for me.

One solution that I though of was using `dynamic_cast`, where each `XContract` inherits from a `BaseContract` class:

```
class AManager
{
    addEntity(Entity e, BaseContract contract);
}

class BManager
{
    addEntity(Entity, BaseContract contract);
}
```

Now I could pass the contract to any of this classes, so I think I would have to use `dynamic_cast` to the correct contract so I can work with them.

- Is this a good solution?

Somehow this seems to me more like a hack than an actual solution, because any kind of `Contract` would be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly its like you have multiple manager type and the user of those are agnostic to the lower layer manager classes, then why don't you use factory method design pattern so that you can plugin new manager easily?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `dynamic_cast` is a good idea and how you decide what type to cast to? you can try template the method `addEntityToManager` and `addEntity`, for example something like this:

```
class   ContractA
{
public:
  std::string add()
  {
    return std::string("adding to contract A");
  }
};

class   ContractB
{
public:
  std::string add()
  {
    return std::string("adding to contract B");
  }
};

class   ManagerA
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  void  addEntity(T contract)
  {
    std::cout << "Manager A " << contract.add() << std::endl;
  }
};

class   ManagerB
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  void  addEntity(T contract)
  {
    std::cout << "Manager B " << contract.add() << std::endl;
  }
};

class   ComponentManager
{
public:
  template<typename T, typename U>
  void  addEntityToManager(T contract, U manager)
  {
    manager.addEntity(contract);
  }
};
```

and this test,

```
int     main()
{
  ManagerA manA;
  ManagerB manB;
  ContractA contA;
  ContractB contB;
  ComponentManager compM;

  compM.addEntityToManager(contA, manA);
  compM.addEntityToManager(contA, manB);
  compM.addEntityToManager(contB, manA);
  compM.addEntityToManager(contB, manB);

  return 0;
}
```

will produce output:

```
Manager A adding to contract A
Manager B adding to contract A
Manager A adding to contract B
Manager B adding to contract B
```

you can add template specializations where is needed :)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that `ManagerA` and other Managers are not accessible to the user. So I can not pass them as arguments